# Python dm.xmlsec "signature verification failed"

Tags: python, openssl, x509certificate, signature

I want to verify Windows Mobile InApp Receipt with public key 
 I have certificate (.cer) from that I got .pem file and from that I got public key
 Here is my code :

```
import dm.xmlsec.binding as xmlsec
xmlsec.initialize()
from os.path import dirname, basename
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import tostring
def verify_file(xml_file, key_file):
     """verify signature in *xml_file* with key in *key_file*.

     *xml_file* contains the signed XML document.
     It can be a file, a filename string or an HTTP/FTP url.

     *key_file* contains the PEM public key. It must be a filename.

     An exception is raised when the verification fails.
     """
     from lxml.etree import parse
     doc = etree.parse(xml_file)
     node = doc.find(".//{%s}Signature" % xmlsec.DSigNs)
     dsigCtx = xmlsec.DSigCtx()
     # Note: we do not provide read access to `dsigCtx.signKey`.
     #  Therefore, unlike the `xmlsec` example, we must set the key name
     #  before we assign it to `dsigCtx`

     signKey = xmlsec.Key.load(key_file, xmlsec.KeyDataFormatPem, None)
     signKey.name = basename(key_file)
     # Note: the assignment below effectively copies the key
     dsigCtx.signKey = signKey
     dsigCtx.verify(node)

from StringIO import StringIO
if __name__ =="__main__" :
     verify_file('path/of/ReceiptSHA256.xml', 'path/of/pubkey.pem')
```

But problem is giving me error each time when i run it `dsigCtx.verify(node)`:

```
File "_xmlsec.pyx", line 369, in dm.xmlsec.binding._xmlsec.DSigCtx.verify (src/_xmlsec.c:5182) 
dm.xmlsec.binding._xmlsec.VerificationError: ('signature verification failed', 2)
```

and when I debug it then i found actualy `dsigCtx.verify(node)` gives me error 
 `tuple: ('verifying failed with return value', -1)` 
 I have valid certificate, .pem file, public key and receipt but still it is giving me error

Please Help me in this Regards,

Comment: I did not know Windows Mobile had an app store. Did you mean Windows Phone?

Comment: yeah I mean Windows Phone